# How to Prove that a finite-dimensional space can not be isomorphic to an infinite-dimensional one?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know, I know that all people will say that because of their differences and that's why it's not possible, but if someone could help me with an example or with the prove, I would really appreciate it.

The differences are:

(1). There are endomorphisms $T$ with $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ which are not surjective.

(2). Not in every case a linear form $\phi$ is representable by a vector $v$ in presence of a scalar product, i.e., there doesn't exist a vector $v$ that $\phi(.)=\langle v,.\rangle$.

(3). Not all linear mappings are continuos.

(4). You can equip a vector space with two different norms such that the unit ball in respect to the first norm in unbounded in respect to the second.

And sorry for my English I'm not very good.

Comment: It is not really clear what's you are asking for. The body of your questions answers the question in its title perfectly well.

Comment: So you mean that by definition of both, this doesn't happen. Well that's why I put that if someone could give me an example. :c

Comment: An example that this does not happen or you could only argue that this happens because of your definitions? (sorry for my English)

Comment: Btw your "differences" 2-3-4 are specific to vector spaces over $\Bbb R.$

Comment: An *example* cannot prove that something *never* happens. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: So is it okay if I just put  in the prove that this never happens because of the definitions I put, or would you add others?

Comment: You should recall the definition of the dimension and explain why isomorphic vector spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140523/discussion-between-thelast12e1-and-anne-bauval).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic, but is the converse true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3506569/vector-spaces-of-the-same-dimension-are-isomorphic-but-is-the-converse-true)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way to prove it.

Proof: Let $V$ and $W$ be infinite dimensional and finite dimensional vector spaces respectively. Let $\dim W=n$. Suppose that $V$ is isomorphic to $W$. Then there exists a linear map $T : V\to W$ which is injective and surjective. Let $v_1,\dots,v_{n+1}$ be a linearly independent list in $V$. Because an injective linear map  takes a linearly independent list to a linearly independent list, we should have that the list $Tv_1,\dots,Tv_{n+1}$ is linearly independent. But this contradicts the theorem that any list of length $n+1$ cannot be linearly independent in an $n$ dimensional space. Thus, $T$ is not injective and $V$ is not isomorphic to $W$.

Edit: Additionally it also shows that no linear map from an infinite dimensional vector space to a finite dimensional vector space is injective.

Comment: To phrase this proof another way: an infinite-dimensional vector space contains subspaces of any finite dimension, a property that finite-dimensional vector spaces do not share.

Answer (score 1):

That's because, if $T:U\to V$ is an isomorphism, and $B$ a basis of $U$, then $T(B)$ is a basis of $V$. In particular, two isomorphic vector spaces must have the same dimension.

Comment: This is the duplicate mentioned in the comments