# If a vector space and one subspace are both infinite-dimensional. Are they equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

From linear algebra I know this theorem:

If V is a finite-dimensional vector space and W is a subspace of V, then
$$
i)~ dim~ W \leq dim ~V\\
ii) ~dim~ W = dim~ V \longrightarrow W=V
$$
As a lemma: If $dim ~W = \infty$  $\longrightarrow$  $dim~V = \infty$

My question is: Being W a subspace of V, Is this valid?
$$
dim~W=dim~V = \infty \longrightarrow W = V
$$
My tentative answer is no. If V is the vector space of continuous functions, and W is the vector space of polynomials, then W is a subspace of V and is infinite-dimensional, as well as V (by the last lemma). Here $dim~W=dim~V=\infty$ but $W\neq V$.
I would like to ensure this proof is correct, thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Just to clarify, your last paragraph is correct: $V$ and $W$ are *not* necessarily equal. Another example is when $V$ is any infinite dimension vector space and $W=V\oplus V$.

Comment: You can also use the degree of differentiation, from continuous to smooth. All are subspaces and of infinite dimension.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks.

Comment: @ElliotG Yes, a good example.  thanks.

Comment: @MariusS.L. I had not thought of it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments above have given examples where $V\not=W$. In fact we can do even better - we need not even have $V\cong W$ at all!

This is guaranteed to happen if $\vert V\vert>\vert W\vert$, since then there is no bijection between $V$ and $W$ in the first place. "Nice" infinite-dimensional vector spaces like the spaces $\mathsf{ContFunc}$ or $\mathsf{DiffFunc}$ of all continuous or differentiable functions respectively tend to have the same cardinality *(namely $2^{\aleph_0}$ - checking this in the case of the previous two examples is a good exercise)*; however, the space $\mathsf{AllFunc}$ of **all** functions $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is much bigger (it has cardinality $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$). So taking $V=\mathsf{AllFunc}$ and $W=\mathsf{ContFunc}$ (say) gives an example where even isomorphism fails.

The above example may be uncomfortably large at first; we can get a smaller example, at the cost of a somewhat harder proof, by setting (for example) $V=\mathsf{ContFunc}$ and look at the subspace $\mathsf{PolyFunc}$ of *polynomial* functions. The point is that $W$ has dimension $\aleph_0$ while $V$ has dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$; checking each fact is a good exercise. Note that we do have to do this analysis since the spaces have the same cardinality (namely $2^{\aleph_0}$) so the idea of the previous paragraph doesn't work here.

---

Conversely, it's worth noting that we do get isomorphism if $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension *(but "$=\infty$" is too vague here since there are lots of different infinite cardinalities)*: the standard proof for finite-dimensional spaces lifts without change to the infinite-dimensional case, since any bijection between bases extends uniquely to an isomorphism. However, it's worth noting that the axiom of choice plays a crucial role here, and in fact [even saying that all vector spaces *have* bases is equivalent to the axiom of choice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650069/why-is-the-statement-all-vector-space-have-a-basis-is-equivalent-to-the-axiom/1650104#1650104)!